# Electron-Photon entanglement

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Are the electron and photon emerging from a Compton scatter entangled?  If so, what experiment can be done on one that will give information about the other?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two lowest order diagrams of Compton scattering:

[image: compt]

These are an iconic shorthand for writing down the wave function which describes the scatter, and then be able to integrate it for the quantities sought.

Of course all the participating particles are entangled, because entanglement means that there exists a wavefunction common to them.

If you scatter a polarized photon on a polarized electron, the spins of the outgoing photon and electron are "entangled" because of angular momentum conservation, for example.

Comment: ‘Entanglement means that there exists a wave function common to them’ that’s not quite correct.